# R CMD doesn't work on Mac Sierra

Tags: r, macos, rstudio, rjava, microsoft-r

OSX: I use Microsoft-r-open and Rstudio. And R CMD doesn't work on terminal.

```
R CMD javareconf
bash: R: command not found
```

So, I checked R version

```
R --version
bash: R: command not found
```

I can't even find where the location of Microsoft-r-open. It looks like I have to find the path of MRO to export path to .bash_profile.  Is it correct? Can anybody help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself by re-installing MRO
https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/installation/